# Chrome not getting valid CORS request: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cors

I have a problem with a CORS request.
Its URL is:

```
https://rest.opensubtitles.org/search/imdbid-6723592
```

When accessing it via curl, everything looks fine, all the CORS headers are present:

```
curl -s -I -X GET -H 'X-User-Agent: TemporaryUserAgent' https://rest.opensubtitles.org/search/imdbid-6723592
```

Even the OPTIONS verb headers are ok (mandatory since I'm using an additional custom header).

When accessing it from within the browser, Chrome complains:

*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://rest.opensubtitles.org/search/imdbid-6723592' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://rest.opensubtitles.org/search/imdbid-6723592",
        headers: {
            "X-User-Agent": "TemporaryUserAgent"
        },
        success: function (results, status, xhr) {
            console.log("ok");
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log("nok");
        }
    });
```

Any ideas what I'm not seeing?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t show it, use the Network pane in Firefox devtools. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than 200 OK success response?

Comment: It’s imaginable that you might be getting rate limited by the server, in which case it might be responding with, for example, a 429 Too Many Requests error — and in which case the error response might lack the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: @sideshowbarker, indeed, I was getting a 302 for my URL, redirecting to a valid 200 location, but the 302 response was not presenting CORS headers. Thanks for the Firefox suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

For those struggling with this in the future, the problem was that the URL was returning a 302-Redirect, and even though the new location was presenting CORS headers with 200-OK, the initial 302 response was not. Apparently browsers don't follow the 302 to see if the final location presents CORS headers, judging strictly by the initial response headers.